# problem with VNC

Tags: windows-server-2003, vnc

I set a VNC on my server and but when I want to connect to my server with VNC i get this error :

```
" Failed to connect to server"
```

what am i going to do ? thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Check that the firewall is allowing tcp connections to the port number your vnc server is listening to.

Comment: my firewall in now off :D !!!

Comment: and then, can you establish a tcp connection? does the machine respond to your icmp requests? does the vnc server listen to the correct interface?

Answer (score 0):

Check if VNC server is running.

netstat -a